# Unable to position the UL with the input

Tags: html, css

I want to position the list under the input, what is wrong by my css?

[See Example](https://jsfiddle.net/BNDeveloper/rxm268yd/15/)

In this example the nested menu is positioned too far to the left and a little too high (it should start vertically where the containing menu ends).

```
.combobox-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 20em;
  min-height: 1.5em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.combobox-label {
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
}

.combobox-input {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  width: 50%;
}

.combobox-options {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  max-height: 15em;
  overflow-y: auto;
  left: 0;
  top: calc(100% + 0.25em);
  z-index: 100;
  display: block;
}

.combobox-option {
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
```

````
<div class="combobox-wrapper">
   <label for="combobox-input" class="combobox-label">
     Countries
   </label>
   <input id="combobox-input" />
   <ul id="combobox-listbox" role="listbox" class="combobox-options">
     <li tabindex="0" id=":rl:-BZ" role="option" value="BZ" class="combobox-option highlighted"><span>Belize</span></li>
     <li tabindex="0" id=":rl:-BJ" role="option" value="BJ" class="combobox-option"><span>Benin</span></li>
   </ul>
 </div>

```
````

Comment: _"what is wrong by my css?"_ - how could we tell, you did not even include it. (Yes, you have linked to a jsfiddle - not enough, a proper [mre] of your issue belongs _directly_ into your question.)

Comment: With `left: 50%` it should be in about the correct position - at least as long as the label and the inout both render at about half the width of the flex parent. If you wanted to position it directly in relation to the inout field - then you would need a different structure, input and list would need to be in a common relative wrapper element then.

Comment: @CBroe You are right, can you help me to make it related to the input field

Comment: Maybe, if you make this a proper question first (see first comment.)

Comment: @CBroe I updated my question, i hope you can help me now

Comment: Like I said, just put the input and the list into a wrapper div, and then apply `position:relative` to that - https://jsfiddle.net/Lx7ec8b3/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you mean this or not but you can try this:

**index.html**

```
<div class="combobox-wrapper">
<div>
<label for="combobox-input" class="combobox-label">
Countries
</label>
<input id="combobox-input" />
</div>
<div>
<ul id="combobox-listbox" role="listbox" class="combobox-options">
<li tabindex="0" id=":rl:-BZ" role="option" value="BZ"
class="combobox-option highlighted"><span>Belize</span></li>
<li tabindex="0" id=":rl:-BJ" role="option" value="BJ"
class="combobox-option"><span>Benin</span></li>
<li tabindex="0" id=":rl:-BM" role="option" value="BM"
class="combobox-option"><span>Bermuda</span></li>
<li tabindex="0" id=":rl:-BT" role="option" value="BT"
class="combobox-option"><span>Bhutan</span></li>
<li tabindex="0" id=":rl:-BO" role="option" value="BO"
class="combobox-option"><span>Bolivia</span></li>
<li tabindex="0" id=":rl:-BA" role="option" value="BA"
class="combobox-option"><span>Bosnia and Herzegovina</span></li>
<li tabindex="0" id=":rl:-BW" role="option" value="BW"
class="combobox-option"><span>Botswana</span></li>
<li tabindex="0" id=":rl:-BV" role="option" value="BV"
class="combobox-option"><span>Bouvet Island</span></li>
<li tabindex="0" id=":rl:-BR" role="option" value="BR"
class="combobox-option"><span>Brazil</span></li>
<li tabindex="0" id=":rl:-IO" role="option" value="IO"
class="combobox-option"><span>British Indian Ocean Territory</span></li>
<li tabindex="0" id=":rl:-BN" role="option" value="BN"
class="combobox-option"><span>Brunei Darussalam</span></li>
<li tabindex="0" id=":rl:-BG" role="option" value="BG"
class="combobox-option"><span>Bulgaria</span></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

**style.css**

```
.combobox-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 20em;
    min-height: 1.5em;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: var(--form-field-border-radius);
    outline: none;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  
  }
  
  .combobox-label {

    color: var(--color-text-dark-gray);
    padding-top: 0.5em;
  }
  
  .combobox-input {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #4d4d4d;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #828995;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    width: 50%;
  }
  
  .combobox-options {

    list-style: none;
    max-height: 15em;
    overflow-y: auto;
    border: 0.05em solid var(--color-bg-gray);
    border-radius: var(--form-field-border-radius);
    left: 0;
    top: calc(100% + 0.25em);
    background-color: var(--color-white);
    z-index: 100;
    display: block;
  }
  
  .combobox-option {
    padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

Comment: No, i want the label to be on the left, and the list to be under the input exactly and with the same width